# Get time difference in minutes or seconds in spark sql

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I have a table like so:

```
# Sample table
building |   date     |  start_time          |  end_time
-----------------------------------------------------------------
  A      | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 08:30:42  | 2019-01-01 08:30:50
  A      | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 09:20:52  | 2019-01-01 09:20:56
  A      | 2019-01-02 | 2019-01-02 10:21:12  | 2019-01-02 10:21:20
  B      | 2019-01-01 | 2019-01-01 06:53:22  | 2019-01-01 06:53:27
  B      | 2019-01-02 | 2019-01-02 07:56:36  | 2019-01-02 07:56:41
  B      | 2019-01-02 | 2019-01-02 08:45:08  | 2019-01-02 08:45:15
```

I want to get the time difference in seconds between `start_time` and `end_time`, grouped by `building` and `date`. The following code using `date_diff` works in Athena or Presto, but not Spark SQL. Is there a way to do this in Spark SQL?

```
# Works in Athena or Presto but not Spark SQL
select 
  building,
  date,
  avg(date_diff('minute', start_time, end_time)) as length
from schema.table
group by 1, 2

# Outcome in Athena or Presto
building   |     date     | length
---------------------------------------
  A        |  2019-01-01  |   6 
  A        |  2019-01-02  |   8
  B        |  2019-01-01  |   5
  B        |  2019-01-02  |   6
```

P.S. I know how to do `groupby` operations in SparkR or PySpark. I'm only interested in a Spark SQL solution here.

Comment: Can you please add an example of input with its desired output?

Comment: I've added an example table and outcome